# Pandas to JSON, Multiple Hierarchy

Tags: python, json, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame looking like this:

|  | EMPLOYEE_ID | NAME | MANAGER EMPLOYEE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ID_1 | ABC1 | NaN |
| 1 | ID_2 | ABC2 | ID_1 |
| 2 | ID_3 | ABC3 | ID_1 |
| 3 | ID_4 | ABC4 | ID_3 |
| 4 | ID_5 | ABC5 | ID_2 |

The goal here was to print a Tree Json:

```
{
   "employeeID":"  ",
   "name":"  ",
   "reportees":[
      {
         "employeeID":xx1,
         "name":yy1,
         "reportees":[
            {
               "employeeID":xx11,
               "name":yy22
            }
         ]
         }
      ]
}
```

The approach I used here was to create a MultiIndex, something like this.

```py
multi_df2 = df.set_index(["MANAGER EMPLOYEE_ID", "EMPLOYEE_ID", "NAME"]).sort_index()
```

But I was unable to convert the resultant DF into JSON, then I used Lamda operation and GrouBy

```
df4 = (df.groupby(["EMPLOYEE_ID"])['MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID', 'NAME']
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
       .to_json()
      )
```

to generate the following JSON:

```
{
   "employeeID":"  ", # MANAGER
      {
         "employeeID":xx1,
         "name":yy1
      },
      {
         "employeeID":xx2,
         "name":yy2
      },
      {
         "employeeID":xx3,
         "name":yy3
      },
   "employeeID":"  ", # MANAGER2
      {
         "employeeID":xx12,
         "name":yy12
      },
      {
         "employeeID":xx13,
         "name":yy13
      },
      {
         "employeeID":xx14,
         "name":yy14
      }
}
```

And am not sure how to increase the hierarchy from here on, any help is appreciated.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052053/pandas-dataframe-to-json-hierarchy) solution is quite similar but the selected answer says that this is not possible with `pandas` as, "the data structure you're going after is recursive, not tabular." Which am unable to understand.

EDIT 1:

I performed a merge operation in order to obtain the Manager Name:

```
manager_df = merged_df3.merge(merged_df3[["EMPLOYEE_ID", "NAME"]], left_on="MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID", right_on="EMPLOYEE_ID", how='left').drop("EMPLOYEE_ID_y", axis=1)
```

The Dataframe looks like this as of now:

| EMPLOYEE_ID | NAME | MANAGER_EMPLOYEE_ID | MANAGER_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | S | 40 | G |
| 40 | G | nan | nan |
| T | M | 40 | G |
| 0c | H | 42 | S |